# What is the best way to create custom login page in liferay

Tags: liferay-6

I have downloaded the liferay 6 with tomcat bundle and installed it.I am getting redirected to Liferay login page when i hit the default liferay url. But my requirement is

```
1)I should redirect to the login page of my own when clicks on the sigin button.
2)After clicking on submit button of login page , the user will get authenicated against "Login" table created by me.
3)After authentication the user will redirect to Liferay landing page.
```

Please share some sample code if available for this kind of requirement.It is very urgent to me.If this is not the correct place to place the liferay related question please give me the link to post my problems.Thank You.

Hi Vikas here i am editing the question according to your answaer.

I have created a hook with below steps.

1)In Eclipse IDE File - New - Project - LiferayProject - clicks on Next button then Given the project name and then selected the checkbox for hook and clicks on finish button.

2)In liferay-hook.xml i have added /WEB-INF/jsps

3)I have created the following directory structure.
login-hook/docroot/WEB-INF/jsps/html/portlet/login/login.jsp

4)In login.jsp i have placed the code of liferay-portal6.1/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/html/portlet/login/login.jsp file.

When i do like this it is showing so many red marks in my jsp file like HtmlUtil can not be resoled.Like this it is showing so many errors.Am i doing anything wrong here.Please let me know the problem.I am very new to liferay.Thank You.

Hi Vikas.This is the code i am using in my login.jsp.

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Login using jsp</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <H1>LOGIN FORM</H1>
            <form>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Username  : </td><td> <input name="username" size=15 type="text" /> </td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Password  : </td><td> <input name="password" size=15 type="text" /> </td> 
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="login" />
            </form>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1.` Create a `hook` for overriding default login page of Liferay

`2.` The portal can authenticate users based on their email address, screen name, or user id.
     This is set in `portal-ext.properties`

```
    company.security.auth.type=emailAddress  //This enables authentication to happen through Email Address
    #company.security.auth.type=screenName
    #company.security.auth.type=userId
```

Adding your own table might cause a problem in future if the next release of Liferay plans to add table of the name that you will be giving now!

`3.` Set `default.landing.page.path` to whichever path you want Users to land after authentication. 
   This is set in `portal-ext.properties`. It can also be configured through Admin port.

If you are looking for code then please check the FAQ section [here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Hi Vikas Very Thanks For giving the reply.I have edited my original question according to your answer.I am strucked up in the first step of your answer itself.Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: `HtmlUtil.escape` is used to escape characters. They can be found in the class `HtmlUtil`. In your customized JSP, check if you have imported init.jsp of Liferay. `<%@ include file="/html/portlet/login/init.jsp" %>`. You don't have to import any Jars for this. init.jsp loads many utilitiy classes

Comment: yes.In my customized jsp i have imported the init.jsp of liferay.Do i need to copy this init.jsp and place it in hook.

Comment: Ok.I have modified my login.jsp as my requirement.It is showing the login page.But when i click on submit button it is not login.What should be the problem.Do i need to write any java class(spring) for this.I have posted the login.jsp code in my original question.

Comment: There is no action associated with this Submit. Its not invoking the class required for authentication. Check the originial Liferay's login page. And check the action associated with Submit.